# If/then statement comparing OSX app to specific version

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, script

Having trouble making a simple script that outputs if the version matches or if it doesn't. Using VS Code as an example.

I input this in terminal:

```
osascript -e 'version of app "Visual Studio Code"'
```

and get

```
1.73.1
```

so then my logic took to me to write:

```
#!/bin/bash/

vsversion=(osascript -e 'version of app "Visual Studio Code"')

 if [ $vsversion == "1.73.1" ]; 
    then 
        echo "Equal"
    else   
        echo "Not Equal"
 fi
```

this outputs

```
Not Equal
```

What am I doing wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, twas missing that extra "$" - facepalm but learning moment!

```
vsversion=$(osascript -e 'version of app "Visual Studio Code"')
```

yielded the correct response vs

```
vsversion=(osascript -e 'version of app "Visual Studio Code"')
```

which did not

Answer (score 0):

bash [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) syntax is `$(...)`

Compare

```bash
vsversion=(osascript -e 'version of app "Visual Studio Code"')
declare -p vsversion
```

outputs (it's an array)

```bash
declare -a vsversion=([0]="osascript" [1]="-e" [2]="version of app \"Visual Studio Code\"")
```

to

```bash
unset vsversion
vsversion=$(osascript -e 'version of app "Visual Studio Code"')
#.........^
declare -p vsversion
```

this is better (my version is a little out-of-date)

```bash
declare -- vsversion="1.63.2"
```

---

After that, take care to quote **any** variable within `[...]`

```bash
 if [ "$vsversion" == "1.73.1" ];
```